# How to increase the fetching speed of data from Oracle using PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo

I am developing a website which is fetching data from Oracle database on another server. But the problem is that database contains more than 50 million records and more than 10 records are added to the database every second. When I use following code to fetch records it took around 3-4 minutes to load the page :

```
<?php
    $qry="SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 where col1=parameter1";
    $stid = oci_parse($db_con, $qry);
    oci_execute($stid);
    $r = oci_fetch_all($stid, $result, 0, -1, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW); //**** PROBLEM
    oci_free_statement($stid);
?>
```

The marked line takes a huge lot of time to load the data. I have also tried foreach loop with oci_fetch_assoc() function but same problem. I have used PDO also but speed is same. This query retrieves almost 100 records.

How can I speed up the page?

I am free to use any other technology with PHP..

Comment: Is `col1` indexed correctly? If you are trying to query on a where clause that does not have an index, its probably doing a full table scan.

Comment: To add to @datasage (beyond that he is most likely spot on), adding an index on a database of that size that has a lot of inserts does not come free of its pitfalls either.

Comment: If your query is only returning less than 100 records, the problem is probably on the database side of things. Do you have an index on `col1`? Otherwise, it is likely that the database is doing a table scan, which is indeed slow with 50 million records.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson is correct. This is very likely a database issue. If you have  DBA you may want to work this out with them.

Comment: also it sounds like you might have some possible disk contention. reading while so many writes are going on. - partitioning and striping may be options

Comment: @Randy I'm not sure I'd classify 10 writes per second as "so many", but depending on how many indexes also need updating, you may have a point.

Comment: col1 is not indexed and yes it is doing a full table scan... we can't modify the table .... so can anyone help me... I am allowed to use any other technology along with php... please help me out ASAP....

Comment: @NiteshGupta You won't be able to speed up this query without modifying the data structure. If you don't need real-time results, you could work on a copy of the table that is indexed and refreshed periodically.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat ... I need fresh data... and am not allowed to do any changes in database ... I am allowed to do anything on web server... what can be done????

Comment: @NiteshGupta Your requirement is not reasonable. You can't expect a 50+ million rows full table scan to be instantaneous. The most reasonable solution is to build an index. You need to work on that with your DBA: if your query is used frequently, then the extra load on the database will be much more costly than updating a single index. If your query is not used frequently, then waiting 3-4 minutes may not really be a problem.